# Querying MediaWiki API for random articles with both extracts and thumbnails

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm building a web app that is using httpRequests to query the Wikipedia API. Ideally I need the API call to return at least 12 random articles that have BOTH a thumbnail and an extract, but I'm struggling to work out if this is possible.

My query url at the moment is:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts%7Cpageimages&generator=random&redirects=1&exlimit=max&exintro=1&explaintext=1&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=300&pilimit=max&pilicense=any&grnnamespace=0&grnfilterredir=nonredirects&grnlimit=100&origin=*
```

It returns plenty of articles but of the 20 that I can return the extracts for not all of those are guaranteed to also have thumbnails (it's usually <8). Is there any way to query the API for only those articles that have both an extract and a thumbnail?

Comment: No this isn't possible as far as I know. You'll need to make the call and then exclude any without both.

Comment: You could use [list=pageswithprop](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bpageswithprop) with the `page_image` property name but it will be very much non-random.